# Can I use ng-repeat and have isolated scope with angular component?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

So I have a ng repeat block that passes an object to a angular component. That looks like this

```
<div ng-repeat="assessor in $ctrl.dedupeDetail.matches">
    <assessordedupequickcard assessor="assessor"></assessordedupequickcard>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

I thought it might be helpful to add what the component is defined as. Here is that code

```
angular.module('assessor.dedupe')
    .component('assessordedupequickcard', {
        controller: 'assessorDedupeQuickcardController',
        templateUrl: 'src/app/assessor/dedupe/quickcard/assessor.dedupe.quickcard.html',
        bindings: {
            assessor: '<',
        }
    });
```

**End Edit**

The quickcard takes the various fields in the assessor object such as name, address, phone numbers, age, etc, and displays them cleanly in a small box that is supposed to represent a contact card for that person.

In that quickcard are two labels

```
<label ng-if="$ctrl.isSource" class="quickcard-list-header pull-right">FROM</label>
<label ng-if="$ctrl.isTarget" class="quickcard-list-header pull-right">TO</label>
```

In the view where the list of these, "contact cards" is displayed there is a functionality where you can select one card, then select another, and transfer information from one to the other.

When selecting the first

```
<assessordedupequickcard assessor="assessor"></assessordedupequickcard>
```

from the ng-repeated list I need to flip a flag that exists within that < assessordedupequickcard > component's scope in its controller and flip isSource = true.

And when selecting the second

```
<assessordedupequickcard assessor="assessor"></assessordedupequickcard>
```

from the ng-repeated list, again move one layer deeper into that custom component's controller and flip its isTarget = true.

But I cannot figure out how to isolate which component will have a flag flip. Because they are not individually named they are all treated as one. Any change I make to one of the repeated custom components happens to all of the custom components.

I'm not sure I've explained this well, if there's any more info I can provide please let me know. Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide me in regards to this.

Comment: So to summarize ... you click one of the two ng-repeated items. when clicked, certain property of the clicked component gets changed (flagged).. you wanna know which of those two changed from the parent controller ... am i understanding it correctly?

Comment: @PrashantGhimire correct. When clicking on one of the ng-repeated items, of which there can be as few as 2 or as many as 15-20, I need to change a specific property inside the component's controller that was clicked on, while the other components and their controller's properties remain unchanged.

Comment: Got you .. will make a demo for it ...

Comment: Check this out .. is this what you want ? https://embed.plnkr.co/0aYm5SYvjjHFyOBCPApQ/

Comment: Yeah that's the exact functionality I need! I'm trying to sort out how to apply it to my own stuff right now. Thanks so much for assembling that demo!

Comment: No prob. Glad to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular components always have isolated scope ([components documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)). Now, you just need to implement two-way binding and pass the data object. This makes the controller (that contains repeated components) aware of any data changes occurring within each components distinctly.

**Page HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
  <h3>Repeated Components with Isolated Scope: </h3>
  <box ng-repeat="data in collection track by $index" data="data"></box>

  <h3>Parent Controller:</h3>
  <pre>{{collection| json}}</pre>
</div>
```

**Page JS:**

```
.controller('SampleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.collection = [{
    name: 'A'
  }, {
    name: 'B'
  }, {
    name: 'C'
  }, {
    name: 'D'
  }, {
    name: 'E'
  }];

})
```

**Component JS:**

```
.component('box', {
    bindings: {
      data: '=?'
    },
    templateUrl: 'box.html',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: function() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.toggle = function() {
        vm.data.flagged = !vm.data.flagged;
      }
    }
  });
```

**Component HTML:**

```
<div class="box" ng-click="vm.toggle()">
  <p>{{vm.data}}</p>
</div>
```

**[Plunker Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/0aYm5SYvjjHFyOBCPApQ/)**